# Can I upload files with filenames containing "*" character on web-host?

Tags: linux, apache, filenames

I got a bunch of image files with "*" character in their filename. Everything is working fine if I include the files in my local web-server.

Is there any reason not to upload them on the web-host.

Comment: Even if technically you could, you pragmatically should not do that (it could confuse users, scripts, sysadmins, etc...) Did you consider writing a script or program which would replace the `*` with a `_` or perhaps a `+` (and perhaps a uniquely generated suffix to the basename).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THat depends on file system used. Different file systems allow different sets of characters for file names.

Comment: I am using Linux-based webhosting. The file system allows filenames with asterisks characters. So ? I can upload ?

Comment: Then it is possible. I'd not recommend it, because of extra care needed to be taken with specifying file names, proper quoting in scripts, and the off chance that one or another program doesn't deal with * in name correctly. Most do, at least of those I'm frequently using. As your question is "is there any reason not to" then yes, those are some reasons. Only because you can doesn't mean you have to. Defensive naming would be less challenging with - in depth testing with special chars like * has probably not done extensively with every program.

Comment: I also assume "files system allows it" means that it specifies * as a legal char, rather than merely "it stores those files without complaining" - The fact that it's Linux doesn't mean that the file system allows it, as Linux supports dozens of different file systems.